# Spark scala dataframe finding max

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am using following to find the max column value.

```
  val d = sqlContext.sql("select max(date), id from myTable group By id")
```

How to do the same query on DataFrame without registering temp table.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to translate that sql to code to be used with a dataframe, you could do something like:

```
df.groupBy("id").max("date").show()
```

Comment: Can I group by on two columns ?

Comment: Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.;
 at org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData$$anonfun$3.apply(GroupedData.scala:92)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData$$anonfun$3.apply(GroupedData.scala:89)

Answer (score 1):

Direct translation to DataFrame Scala API:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(max("date"))
```

Spark 2.2.0 execution plan is identical for both OP's SQL & DF scenarios.

Full code for `spark-shell`:

```
Seq((1, "2011-1-1"), (2, "2011-1-2")).toDF("id", "date_str").withColumn("date", $"date_str".cast("date")).write.parquet("tmp")
var df = spark.read.parquet("tmp")
df.groupBy("id").agg(max("date")).explain

df.createTempView("myTable")
spark.sql("select max(date), id from myTable group By id").explain
```

Answer (score 0):

For max use

```
df.describe(Columnname).filter("summary = 'max'").collect()[0].get(1))
```

And for min use

```
df.describe(Columnname).filter("summary = 'min'").collect()[0].get(1))
```

Comment: This answer is not comprehensive.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer ? One can get all the other statistical value of interest as well. The only performance improvement is to assign the df.describe to a val and then use this value to extract max and min

Answer (score -1):

if you have a dataframe with id and date column, what you can do n spark 2.0.1 is

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
 mydf.groupBy('date').agg({'id':'max'}).show()
```

Comment: similar syntax, but the above is `python` and not `scala`

Answer (score -2):

```
var maxValue = myTable.select("date").rdd.max()
```

Comment: why use `var`? that is a bad paradigm to use for such a variable - unless you intend to use it again.